# couldn't understand why head = head->next works

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, null

I don't know why `head = head->next` works when we have stored nothing or `NULL` in the `head->next`

these are two functions
1st function is taking an argument `n` of `int` type and creates the list in this function we define that `head->next = NULL`

and second function i.e. `deletefirstnode` deletes first node but in this function `head->next` really works and points to another node in the list we use `temp->next` to access the next node but why in this case `head->next`
please somebody explain it for me

```
void createlist(int n){
    struct node *newnode, *temp;
    int data, i;
    
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("unable to allocate memory");
    }
    else{
        printf("enter the data of node 1 : ");
        scanf("%d", &data);
        
        head->data = data;
        head->next = NULL;// here is where we define head->next to NULL
        temp = head;
        
        
        for(i=2; i<=n; i++){
            newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            
            
            if(newnode == NULL){
                printf("unble to allocate memory");
            }
            else{
                printf("enter the data of node %d", i);
                scanf("%d", &data);
                
                newnode->data = data;
                newnode->next = NULL;
                temp->next = newnode;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        printf("singly linked list created successfully\n");
    }
}


void deletefirstnode(){
    struct node *todelete;
    
    if(head == NULL){
        printf("list is already empty");
    }
    else{
        todelete = head;
        head = head->next;//and why this works now I am confused
        
        printf("\ndata deleted = %d\n", todelete->data);
        
        free(todelete);
        
        printf("successfully deleted the first node from list\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `head = head->next;` - Assigning a value to a pointer. Ask yourself what `head` pointed to before, then after, the assignment operation. Don't complicate it with deep thought. Say the first thing that springs to mind. Then, step through your program with a debugger, examining variable values, and see if you were correct.

Comment: `head` is not `NULL` in the `else` case.  Therefore, `head->next` is valid; `head->next` may point to a valid address or `NULL`.  The purpose of the code you're asking about is to delete the current `head` and promote the next in line (if any) to `head`.

Comment: Pointing to and storing is quite different, I think you should think more about pointing to something more than storing when you use pointer

Comment: Welcome to SO. Such questions regarding linked list management are best started with pen&paper. Draw the nodes on paper should be rather useful.

Comment: @Rahul Magar Explain why this  head = head->next shall not work in your opinion.

Answer (score 0):

In your program head you have not globally declared head as `NULL` so `head` is pointing to somewhere in the linked list in which you have previously used `head`. If `head->next` had not been `NULL` then your Singly Linked List will have no end. And for the delete,i.e,

```
todelete = head;
head = head->next;
free(todelete)
```

`todelete` stores the address of the `head` and then you point your `head` to next so as to cut the current link of `head` and point it to the next address,otherwise the node which you want to delete will remain in the memory.